# Writing style to prevent string concatenation in a list of strings

Tags: python, code-structure

Suppose I have a list/tuple of strings,

```py
COLOURS = [
    "White",
    "Black",
    "Red"
    "Green",
    "Blue"
]

for c in COLOURS:
    # rest of the code
```

Sometimes I forget placing a comma after each entry in the list (`"Red"` in the above snippet). This results in one `"RedGreen"` instead of two separate `"Red"` and `"Green"` list items.

Since this is valid Python, no IDE/text editor shows a warning/error. The incorrect value comes to the limelight only during testing.

What writing style or code structure should I use to prevent this?

Comment: Looks like there isn't much of a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71309795/design-decision-to-avoid-having-python-merge-strings-in-a-list

Comment: Parenthesizing each string would turn any missing comma into an error - but that just moves the problem from remembering commas to remembering parentheses.

Comment: You could go about it another way; might seem like overkill but it could have its benefits - you could have a separate file with the list of items separated by newlines, then read in that file as a list. Or, define all the items in your code in a multiline string, then split by lines.

Comment: I am not sure how to check for it, but this seems like the kind of thing that could be detected by a static linter (search for two string literals with no operators between them?). I wonder if you could propose this to PEP 8 to include this as a warning?

Comment: @JRose "Two or more string literals (i.e. the ones enclosed between quotes) next to each other are automatically concatenated." - Python docs. This can't be considered a warning since it's a language feature.

Comment: @Shiva I could be completely wrong, but because PEP8 is a “style guide” I believe it will flag many things that you and I can agree are language features as warnings. This would be a useful warning for those running a static linter because it is (I assume) a very rarely used language feature and more often likely an unintended bug.

Comment: @JRose Pylint will find this problem, but only if the strings are on the same line. The rule is "implicit-str-concat (W1404)". **Edit**: Oh, actually, it has a flag [`check-str-concat-over-line-jumps`](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#check-str-concat-over-line-jumps) that will find it even if the strings aren't on the same line.

Comment: I found this old PEP feature request to disallow this, which failed. I wonder if we could ask them to reconsider with the stipulation that it should raise a warning but still be allowed? https://peps.python.org/pep-3126/

Comment: @JRose Good find! Implicit string concatenation goes against "explicit is better than implicit" philosophy.

Comment: I have also confirmed that PEP8 still does not flag this as an error, so there was no approved proposal after the one mentioned above.

Comment: I personally have gotten in the habit of *always* putting a trailing commas in multi-line containers and argument lists.  I know it's a bit of a non-answer, but this is easily solved by just never forgetting, lol.

Comment: If you are concerned about implicit string joining, don't use multiple string literals: use a single string that must be split. E.g., `COLORS = "White Black Red Green Blue".split()`. For any list whose elements you were explicitly enumerating, the overhead should be minimal. (That is, I'm assuming you weren't defining a list of hundreds of elements or more.)

Comment: Also, if you have tests that catch this, good! It means this is just an inconvenience, not a "real" problem.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question, so it's off-topic. But my recommendation is to write code more slowly or with more caffeine.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the linked question. I am aware, as evident from my question, of "why trailing commas are allowed..". Also, I don't think this is opinion-based. After a period of time certain best practices/coding styles are developed by the community that helps the developer write less error-prone code. I was looking for such a code style and apparently as per most of the comments there's no such "style" atm. @wjandrea's comment about the two Pylint flags is probably the closest answer to this question.

Comment: @Shiva I agree it's not opinion-based, but mostly because of the false assumption *"no IDE/text editor shows a warning/error"*, as I addressed in [my answer](/a/73588070/4518341). The wording, *"What writing style or code structure should I use to prevent this?"* is inherently opinion-based because of "should". If you rephrased it as *"**Is there** a writing style or code structure I **could** use to prevent this?"*, that'd be better. But maybe this is semantics, IDK.

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks for editing the question and making _my_ intention clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're incorrect that "no IDE/text editor shows a warning/error". [**Pylint**](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/) can identify this problem using rule [implicit-str-concat (W1404)](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/implicit-str-concat.html) with flag [check-str-concat-over-line-jumps](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#check-str-concat-over-line-jumps). (And for that matter, there are lots of things that are valid Python that a linter will warn you about, like [bare `except:`](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E722.html) for example.)

Personally, I'm using VSCode, so I enabled Pylint via the Python extension (`python.linting.pylintEnabled`) and [set up a pylintrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448731/how-do-i-create-a-pylintrc-file) like this:

```
[tool.pylint]
check-str-concat-over-line-jumps = yes
```

Now VSCode gives this warning for your list:

> **Implicit string concatenation found in list**  pylint(implicit-str-concat)  [Ln 4, Col 1]

---

Lastly, there are probably other linters that can find the same problem, but Pylint is the first one I found.

Answer (score 1):

Using what @wjandrea found, here is a possible solution. It is not pretty, but it can correctly detect that this code has implicit string concatenation. I had it just print out the warning instead of crashing, but if you want it could be modified to throw an error.

You could also just run `pylint` on your file, but I assumed you were looking for a "programmatic" way to detect when this, and only this, occurs.

```
import pylint.lint
import sys

def check_for_implicit_str_concat():
    pylint.lint.reporters.json_reporter.JSONReporter.display_messages = lambda self, layout: None

    options = [
        sys.argv[0], 
        '--output-format=pylint.reporters.json_reporter.JSONReporter',
        '--check-str-concat-over-line-jumps=y'
    ]
    results = pylint.lint.Run(options, do_exit=False)
    for message in results.linter.reporter.messages:
        if message['message-id'] == 'W1403':
            print(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_for_implicit_str_concat()
    COLOURS = [
        "White",
        "Black",
        "Red"
        "Green",
        "Blue"
    ]
```

Output:

```
{
  "type": "warning",
  "module": "test",
  "obj": "",
  "line": 22,
  "column": 0,
  "path": "test.py",
  "symbol": "implicit-str-concat-in-sequence",
  "message": "Implicit string concatenation found in list",
  "message-id": "W1403"
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a coding style and not a "programmatic" way. Even though I was asking for a coding style, enabling the two Pylint flags in my IDE should do what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with an approach like this, which may even increase the maintainability and extensibility of the colours:

- Use enums (or dictionaries) for colours, that would allow you to use them in the following way: `Colours.RED`, `Colours.BLUE`. Probably the best solution out there, but it really depends on the context of your application.
- Create a very simple `Colour` class that would contain a string field of a colour and a constructor that initialises it. This way, the following code looks like this:

  ```py
  COLOURS = [Colour("white"), Colour("green")]
  ```

  The downside of it are probably over-architecting your code to a certain extent and having to treat colour objects now slightly different (perhaps with `c.get_colour()` or `c.color`. Maybe it's not a downside at all, depending on the scale of your application.
- Another "solution" would be to go in a functional style, creating a function that is very redundant, taking the colour as a string and just returning it back. I'm not a fan of this solution as it may not give you any benefit later.

Most of the time in production code, if you have bunch of constants like this in a list (except the cases where you're defining them specifically for enumeration of some sort), not having them enumerated or anything similar - you're most likely doing something wrong, so the solution would be to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Black`](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) formatter and [`Pylint`](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint) together and you're good to go.

If you have your list like: (without ending comma)

```py
COLOURS = [
    "White",
    "Black",
    "Red"
    "Green",
    "Blue"
]
```

Then after formatting it'll become:

```py
COLOURS = ["White", "Black", "Red" "Green", "Blue"]
```

**They're now in the same line**...So `Pylint` complains about it: [`Implicit string concatenation found in list`](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/implicit-str-concat.html).

If you have your same list but with ending comma:

```py
COLOURS = [
    "White",
    "Black",
    "Red"
    "Green",
    "Blue",
]
```

It'll become:

```py
COLOURS = [
    "White",
    "Black",
    "Red" "Green",
    "Blue",
]
```

Again as you see `Black` forces these to be in one line in either case. So you will get Pylint's warning.